# PHP Regex remove unwanted data

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to be able to remove content from a string of data.

This is an example string from google maps api.

```
Distance: 70.5&#160;mi (about 1 hour 12 mins)<br/>Map data &#169;2009 Google
```

I would like everything in between the brackets `()`. So can I remove everything from either side with `preg_split` ?

Comment: You want to get only the "about 1 hour 12 mins" or to remove everything and get: "Distance: 70.5&#160;mi <br/>Map data &#169;2009 Google"

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is better:

```
$str = "Distance: 70.5&#160;mi (about 1 hour 12 mins)<br/>Map data &#169;2009 Google";

$start = strpos($str, '(') + 1;
$end = strpos($str, ')');
$content = substr($str, $start, $end - $start);
```

But if you are dead-set on using a regex:

```
preg_match($str, '/\((.*?)\)/', $matches);
$content = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match('/\(([^)]*)\)/', $text, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[2];
    // $result now contains everything inside the backets
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basic regular expression problem. Use something like this: `preg_match('/\(.*?\)/', $s, $m);` where `$s` is your string. The matches are going to be in the `$m` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace`:

```
$timeDistance = preg_replace(array('/(.*)([(])(.*)([)])/'), array('\3',''), $googleString );
```

That should extract the text between the parens.

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
// Step 1
$string  = "Distance: 70.5&#160;mi (about 1 hour 12 mins)<br/>Map data &#169;2009 Google";
$pieces = explode("(", $string);
echo $pieces[0]; // should be: Distance: 70.5&#160;mi 
echo $pieces[1]; // should be: about 1 hour 12 mins)<br/>Map data &#169;2009 Google";

// Step 2
$keeper = explode(")", $pieces[1]);
echo $keeper[0]; // should be: about 1 hour 12 mins 
echo $keeper[1]; // <br/>Map data &#169;2009 Google";
```

Comment: This one's a `$keeper`... But do you need those two arrays? Really?