# simple regex help php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string Like this:

```
MyText (1,151)
```

I would like to get with regex only the value inside (), in this case only: 1,151.

I know it is simple but I am not good with regex.

Thanks!

Comment: Get expresso for building and learning regexes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nearly identical question [was just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578717/php-regex-remove-unwanted-data).  There are solutions in there that will work for you ;)

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the question linked, too.  Using a regular expression for something so trivial is usually overkill.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
if (preg_match($str, '/\(([^)]*)\)/', $matches))
{
    $content = $matches[1];
}
```